# How to count the value of a column that matches certain conditions in SEVERAL columns

Tags: python, dataframe, optimization

I´ve been working with a dataframe that has the results of thousands of football games.
Let´s say that I want to know the top 15 teams that have scored more, but I only have the columns of
`hometeam_goals` and `awayteam_goals` and you don´t have the result.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [["Spain","England",3,2],["France","Germany",0,2],["Poland","Gambia",1,4],["England", "Spain",2,2],["France","England",1,0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["home_team","away_team","home_score","away_score"])
```

I have made the calculations doing sustraction between `hometeam_goals` and `awayteam_goals` but I think there should be some way to synthetize it more.

What I have done is creating a new column with the `Home wins`, `Away wins` and `Draw` strings to then use `.value_counts()` and sort it by descending order, which gives me the answer.

```
scores['balance'] = scores['home_score'] - scores['away_score']

scores["result"] = scores["balance"].apply(lambda x: "Home wins" if x > 0 else "Away wins" if x < 0 else "Draw")

#Counting home
scores_home = scores[scores["result"]=="Home wins"]
victories_home = scores_home["home_team"].value_counts()

#Counting away
scores_away = scores[scores["result"] == "Away wins"]
victories_away = scores_away["away_team"].value_counts()

total_vict = victories_home + victories_away
top_15_total_vict = total_vict.sort_values(ascending=False).head(15)
print(total_vict.sort_values(ascending=False).head(15))

print(scores.head())
```

Nevertheless, I think it could be made in less lines, how would you do it to be more optimal?
In addition, I would like to keep it as a DataFrame with the original look rather than a Series, as it allows me to use Seaborn to calculate statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution to find the teams that have won more games:

```
pd.concat([
    df["home_team"][df["home_score"] > df["away_score"]],
    df["away_team"][df["home_score"] < df["away_score"]],
]).value_counts(sort=True)
```

For example, if this is your input dataframe

```
data = [
    ["Spain", "England", 3, 2],
    ["France", "Germany", 0, 2],
    ["Poland", "Gambia", 1, 4],
    ["England",  "Spain", 2, 2],
    ["France", "England", 1, 0],
    ["France", "Spain", 5, 0],
    ["Poland", "France", 0, 2],
    ["Spain", "Poland", 3, 0],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=["home_team", "away_team", "home_score", "away_score"],
)
```

then this would be the output

```
France     3
Spain      2
Germany    1
Gambia     1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering the "*I want to know the top `N` teams that have scored more*" question.

You can reshape with [`lreshape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.lreshape.html), then aggregate the score per country with [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html) and select the top `N` with [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html):

```
N = 3

out = (pd
   .lreshape(df, {'team': ['home_team', 'away_team'],
                  'score': ['home_score', 'away_score']})
   .groupby('team', as_index=False).sum()
   .nlargest(N, columns='score')
)
```

Output:

```
      team  score
5    Spain      5
0  England      4
2   Gambia      4
```